# Deleted the Import All Products Profile from my Import/Export profiles(Magento)

Tags: magento, actionscript, import-from-excel

I accidentally deleted Import All Products profile from Magento admin panel (Data flow/import all products).
How can I create it again.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Follow below steps.**

1. Go to `System > Import/Export > Dataflow - Profiles`
2. Click `Add New Profile`
3. Type `Import All Products` in `Name` field
4. Select `CSV / Tab separated` in `Type` field
5. Select `No` in `Original Magento attribute names in first row` field
6. Click `Save Profile`

Comment: I did this already but when uploading a csv file from local remote server(laptop) it shows following error:      "Could not load file: "/home/bookmyrasoi/public_html/var/export/export_product.csv"."